# Autoscaling in seaborn of axis values and legend

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization

So, I was learning to build deep learning models, and during the visualization part I plotted a scatterplot where x and y axis were longitude and latitude, respectively, and the hue was equal to house prices. Although the price values were in float format, the legend is showing in different scaled value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv("../DATA/kc_house_data.csv")
sns.histplot(df['price'])
```

[image]

```
non_top_1_perct = df.sort_values('price',ascending=False).iloc[216:]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.scatterplot(x= 'long', y= 'lat', data =non_top_1_perct,
           edgecolor = None, alpha = 0.2, palette  ='RdYlGn', hue='price')
```

[image]

Here, in the first picture, one can notice that x-axis scale is in formatted into scientific notation. Also, in the legend box, if I want to show 7,700,000 instead of 1.6, how I have to rescale both of them?

Data: [kaggle house data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LPsKZH7kCqnl8yN4ndF_oCiAdgoyqmZboIs_Z6nDXl0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is your `seaborn` tag correct? Are you using `matplotlib`? If you want to control the legend you can follow this [guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html). It would help if you share some lines of your code, too.

Comment: Sure! I'm sorry I missed that out.

Comment: Please do not make a picture of your data. Please add it as plain text, so someone can copy and past it. Use `df[['lat', 'long', 'price']].to_str()` for example.

Comment: Please add also `non_top_1_perct` or the line how you generated this DataFrame.

Comment: I have added hyperlink to the data, hopefully you will be able to access the data and download it.

Comment: Do you know that you are only use 216 elements with the smallest price by this line `df.sort_values('price',ascending=False).iloc[216:]`. If you want to have the maximum (which is 7.7m) included in your slice you should use `ascending=True`.

Comment: So, suppose even if include those top 1% percent values, but the legend will still show in scientific notation, but I want to them in integer format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can modify your legend based on the values of existing legend entries.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'long': [3, 5, 5, 6, 7], 
    'price':[35e6, 54899767, 57890789, 62890798, 70897871]
})
ax = sns.scatterplot(y="lat", x="long", data=df, hue='price')

# modify legend entries
handles = ax.get_legend().legendHandles
ax.legend(handles, [str(round(float(v.get_label())/1e6,1))+'m' for v in handles] , loc='upper left')

# disable scientific notation on y axis
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

[image: basic scatter]

You have to adapt this to your task.